# How to deploy a Mac Command Line Tool

Tags: xcode, release, command-line-tool

I've created a console application using the Xcode OS X Command Line Tool project template.

When everything is said and done, where are the actual "Release" binaries placed on my machine?  After searching SO, I found out where I could find the "Debug" binaries:

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project/Build/Products/Debug

Where can I find the "Release" binaries?  Or is there additional setup that is needed in Xcode to output these binaries so that I can distribute console application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scheme settings determine whether the Debug or Release version is built. The default scheme builds Debug. If you choose the Archive option in the Product menu Xcode will build the Release version by default. As part of the archive process you select a location for the build product (the executable) to be placed.

By editing the default scheme you can also direct the ordinary build action to create the Release version. You may also add your own custom schemes.