# How can I distribute my OSX command line Apps in my site?

Tags: macos

I'm building OSX commandline apps. it's almost complete.
source code is open'd  in my github.
but I want to distribute its "binary(Execute file)" as free ware but I can't understand the method.
simply should I extract execute file and place my blog?

I'm sorry because my english is poor.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are building a release version of your app as described here [How to deploy a Mac Command Line Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772187/how-to-deploy-a-mac-command-line-tool)

Then you can place the binary on your blog or on any other page. Make sure you are not using any libraries that may be missing from other people Macs.

Note it is always helpful if you add a description what your app does, how it needs to be called (arguments, ...) and maybe give some screenshots or in case of a command line app textual version of outputs.